# How to hide the browser when downloading files from online

Tags: android

I am trying to download a file from an online source of mine. The issue I am having is that the browser window keeps appearing as it load into the download server. Is there some way that I may be able to hide this? I already have this code below in the `doInBackground` portion of an `AsyncTask`, but cant seem to get it to hide the browser bar. Here is my code at this point:

```
private class getErDone extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getApplicationContext());
        progressDialog.setTitle("Downloading Software");
        progressDialog.setMessage("Now Updating, DO NOT TURN OFF DEVICE");
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try{
            Intent goToMarket = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
                    .setData(Uri.parse("http://mydownloadlink.com/myfile?dl=1"));
//**Note** As convincing as it seems, this is not the real download link
            startActivity(goToMarket);

        }catch (UnknownError e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        /*catch (MalformedURLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (IOException t){
            t.printStackTrace();
        }*/

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    }

}
```

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

here is sample from my code, download without browser:

```
private TextView mFileDownloadProgressBarPercent;
private ProgressBar mFileDownloadProgressBar;
private Runnable mFileExecutionTaskAfterDownload;    
public String fileDownloadedResultPath;
```

and asynctask:

```
class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


         // Before starting background thread
         // Show Progress Bar Dialog
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            if(mFileDownloadProgressBar != null)
                mFileDownloadProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if(mFileDownloadProgressBarPercent != null)
                mFileDownloadProgressBarPercent.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }


         // Downloading file in background thread
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
            int count;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
                URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
                conection.connect();

                // getting file length
                int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

                // input stream to read file - with 8k buffer
                InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);

                String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        .toString();
                File folder = new File(extStorageDirectory, "pdf"); // for example we are downloading pdf's so store in pdf dir.
                folder.mkdir();
                File subFolder = new File(extStorageDirectory+"/pdf", "fileId"); // here you can place files by id of category etc..
                subFolder.mkdir();


                String fileName = url.toString().substring(url.toString().lastIndexOf("/")+1);
                fileDownloadedResultPath = subFolder + "/" +  fileName;
                // Output stream to write file
                OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(subFolder + "/" +  fileName);

                byte data[] = new byte[1024];

                long total = 0;

                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                    total += count;
                    publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));

                    // writing data to file
                    output.write(data, 0, count);
                }

                // flushing output
                output.flush();

                // closing streams
                output.close();
                input.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            }

            return null;
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
            if(mFileDownloadProgressBar != null)
                mFileDownloadProgressBar.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
            if(mFileDownloadProgressBarPercent != null)
                mFileDownloadProgressBarPercent.setText(mContext.getString(R.string.downloading_file) + " " + String.format("%s%%",Integer.parseInt(progress[0])+""));
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            if(mFileDownloadProgressBar != null)
                mFileDownloadProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            if(mFileDownloadProgressBarPercent != null)
                mFileDownloadProgressBarPercent.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            if(mFileExecutionTaskAfterDownload != null)
                mFileExecutionTaskAfterDownload.run();
        }

    }
```

Comment: I tried your code, except I changed the write location to `DIRECTORY.Downloads` but something is still wrong. When I try and download the file, I get this error `/Download/app/data/app-release-0.apk: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)` which is pretty obvious as to what that means, I'm just not sure how to fix it. I'll run a few google searches but if you know how to fix it please let me know

Comment: you must have rights to write external storage add them to manifest